# Undefined reference to Clock

Tags: c, date, atmel

Estoy haciendo este pequeño código para contar los números de pulsos de reloj desde que el sistema inicia pero a la hora de compilar me genera el siguiente error:

> Undefined reference to Clock

Adjunto mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned long tiempoPrev = 0;
unsigned long tiempoPrev2 = 0;
long intervalo = 100;
long intervalo2 = 50;

int main(void)
{
  DDRB |= (1 u << DDB4);
  DDRB |= (1 u << DDB3);
  clock_t tiempoAct;
  while (1)
  {
    tiempoAct = clock();
    if ((tiempoAct - tiempoPrev) >= intervalo)
    {
      tiempoPrev = tiempoAct;
      PORTB ^= (1 u << PB3);
    }

    if ((tiempoAct - tiempoPrev2) >= intervalo2)
    {
      tiempoPrev2 = tiempoAct;
      PORTB ^= (1 u << PB4);
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: `clock()` de `time.h` generalmente funciona con el sistema operativo del computador, en tu caso por el código pareces estar usando algún tipo de microprocesador, que por lo general no traen el soporte para esta función por sus limitaciones de hardware (generalmente se usa un RTC externo para llevar el tiempo). Puedes compartirnos el microprocesador que estás utilizando? Podrías también fijarte en la librería `time.h` que estás usando en el proceso de compilación y revisar si tiene alguna nota con respecto a la función `clock()`

Answer (score 0):

De la [librería `time.h` que usa el compilador de AVR](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__time.html):

> Section 7.23.2.1 clock() The type clock_t, the macro CLOCKS_PER_SEC,
> and the function clock() are not implemented. We consider these items
> belong to operating system code, or to application code when no
> operating system is present.

Por lo tanto la función `clock()` no está implementada, espero que esto responda a tu pregunta.

Puedes implementar un timer siguiendo tutoriales como [este](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/tut-c-newbies-guide-avr-timers?page=all#:%7E:text=The%20AVR%20timers%20are%20very,registers%2C%20and%20the%20timer%20interrupts.).